# How to use relative path in spring integration in XML config

Tags: spring, spring-integration

I want to use a relative to my project path for the `directory` attribute

```
<file:inbound-channel-adapter directory="{?relativePathHere?}" channel="In" >
    <int:poller id="poller" fixed-delay="5000" />
</file:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

I am a newbie in SI, could anybody provide the way how a relative(not absolute) path is used for the attribute?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Relative to what?

By default, it's relative to the current working directory...

```
directory="foo/bar"
```

will resolve to `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/foo/bar"`

```
directory="/foo/bar"
```

is absolute: "/foo/bar"`

```
directory="classpath:foo/bar"
```

will resolve to `foo/bar` somewhere on the classpath.

**EDIT**:

To reference a directory in the user's home, you can use Spring Expression Language (SpEL) to get that property:

```
directory="#{systemProperties['user.home']}/foo/bar">
```

Comment: Thanks for explanations. While not everything works in the way you have described.

1) ``directory="classpath:foo/bar"`` not working at all - exceptions while starting a tomcat server.

2) ``directory="/foo/bar"`` - absolute path works great.
3) ``directory="foo/bar"`` - suppose I'm user andrew on Linux machine. Then my user's folder is /home/andrew. Then ``directory="foo/bar"`` is not associated to /home/andrew/foo/bar. Please, help me here to understand your thought.
As you see, for now I could only use absolute path successfully.

Comment: `"While not everything works in the way you have described. ..."` It works __exactly__ the way I described; when using the classpath: prefix you need to put the parent directory on tomcat's classpath. You can also use SpEL; see my edit. In future, please make your questions clearer, such as "how can I reference a directory in the user's home".